# MySQL query to select rows matching criteria and rows related to the matching rows

Tags: mysql

I would like to select all rows where a column matches a criteria, but also select all rows that don't match the criteria, but have a relation to the rows that do match the criteria.

Given a table structure like this:

```
group_id | word
---------+------
       1 |  the
       2 |  cat
       2 |  sat
       3 |   on
       1 |  the
       3 |  mat
```

Given the criteria `WHERE word LIKE '%at%'`, I'd want to get the matching rows

```
       2 |  cat
       2 |  sat
       3 |  mat
```

but I also want to get the related rows. That is, rows with a group_id equalling the group_id of any row matching the criteria, which in this case would be group_id 2 or 3. The final result should be:

```
       2 |  cat
       2 |  sat
       3 |   on
       3 |  mat
```

I think that a self join is the way to go, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: As usual there are loads of ways to skin a cat with MySQL. How can I judge between the different solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.group_id in (select t2.group_id
                     from t t2
                     where t2.word LIKE '%at%'
                    );
```

If you try to do the same thing using `join`, you might get duplicate results.

Comment: I've profiled all three solutions and this one is fractionally quicker than the others.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured out how to do it with a self join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t1`.* 
FROM `test` AS `t1` JOIN `test` AS `t2` 
ON `t1`.`group_id`=`t2`.`group_id`  
WHERE `t2`.`text` LIKE '%at%'
```

I don't know if there is a better (more efficient) way to do this query.

Answer (score 1):

You can join to a derived table that returns all selected `group_id` values:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT group_id
      FROM mytable
      WHERE word LIKE '%at%'
) AS t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id
```

You have to use `DISTINCT` in the subquery, so as to be sure that you get one row per `group_id`, so that the final result doesn't contain any duplicates.

Comment: On my table with about 20,000 rows and an index on the group_id column, this query takes about 30 times longer than either my answer or Gordon Linoff's answer.